# "if" in the past, but is it still a conditional?

Tags: past-tense, conditionals

It's my first post here, so please be gentle with me.

I had a situation where I exchanged couple of emails with another person couple of day ago. Then after the exchange I don't remember if the person called me by the phone, so I'm trying to write an email with a question about that to this particular person.

This is what I'm trying to come up with, but it became super complex to me:

> I think I missed your latest email on Friday, or did I ? Could you please remind me if we had spoken by the phone after you had sent me an email ?

Especially I'm interested in the part of the sentence after `if`.

I think the sentence is incorrect because sending the email part should be more in the past then the phone call conversation, but there is no more past in English.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You just need to say _Could you please remind me if we spoke on the phone after you sent me an email?_ You might say that he perfect tense ("had sent") is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "after".

Comment: This is not a conditional construction. *If* here means *whether*.

Comment: Agreed with Clare <p> @matewilk: are you asking this person whether s/he called you at all? If so : Could you remind me whether we spoke after our email exchange on Friday?<p>You don't need an extra layer of past tense in your case, but if I were telling someone tomorrow about this response, I could say : Yesterday, I wrote to matewilk to suggest that he ask the person whether s/he had called him after their email exchange on Friday. This last is referred to as reported or indirect speech.